# GWT: Difference access file paths with "/" or "\\" between IE,Chrome and FireFox

Tags: gwt, cross-browser, frame, backslash, slash

In IE and Chrome, if I set an URL "http://example.net/uploads\upload.html" to a Frame.
It works fine. However, in FireFox, it will pops up an 404 error NOT_FOUND: "RequestURI=/uploads%5Cupload.html". this "%5C" should be a "\".

Finally, I change all "\" to "/", it works fine for all browsers.

Can any body explain this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because the backslash `\` is actually invalid to be used as separator? The fact that IE and Chrome accept it doesn't valid it in any way. You should always use the forwardslash '/'. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator